# Why is wordpress backend / dashboard extremely slow on MAMP on OS X?

Tags: wordpress, performance, admin, mamp, dashboard

I find that running Wordpress dashboard / admin using MAMP on OS X is incredibly slow.

Can anyone advise any reasons why it should be so slow? Page loads take several seconds. It is faster using the dashboard on the live site!

Any help greatly appreciated,

thanks!

P